# Discriminant of Quadratic with circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, quadratics

The circle $x^2 + (y - c)^2 = r^2$, where $c > 0$ and $r > 0$, lies inside the parabola $y = x^2$.  The circle touches the parabola at exactly two points located symmetrically on opposite sides of the 
$y$-axis, as shown in the diagram.

[image: parabola_with_internally_tangent_circle]

Show that $4c = 1 + 4r^2$.

My friend asked me how to do the question, and what I did was solve the curves simultaneously, and in doing so got

$ y^2+y(1-2c)+c^2-r^2=0 $

After this I let $\Delta$ equal 0, and the answer comes out. However, my friend then asked me why. I told him it was because the curve is a tangent to the circle, but then he told me there were two points of intersection.

So now am I doubting myself. Can someone explain, logically, why it should be 0? Is it because the y values produced when the circle is a tangent are essentially the same so they are counted as 1 root? Very confused right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

What you are doing by substituting $y$ for $x^2$ is solving for the y-values of the points of intersection of the curves $x^2 + (y - c)^2 = r^2$ and $y = x^2$.

If the discriminant is equal to zero, then the parabola and circle are tangent.  If the discriminant were positive, the parabola and circle would intersect at four points (since there are two $x$-values for each value of $y$ that solves the quadratic equation $y + (y - c)^2 = r^2$).  If the discriminant were negative, the circle and parabola would not intersect.

Since 
\begin{align*}
y + (y - c)^2 & = r^2\\
y + y^2 - 2cy + c^2 - r^2 & = 0\\
y^2 + (1 - 2c)y + c^2 - r^2 & = 0  
\end{align*}
has discriminant 
\begin{align*}
\Delta & = b^2 - 4ac\\\
       & = (1 - 2c)^2 - 4(1)(c^2 - r^2)\\
       & = 1 - 4c + 4c^2 - 4c^2 - 4r^2\\
       & = 1 - 4c - 4r^2
\end{align*}
and the two curves are tangent when $\Delta = 0$, $4c = 1 - 4r^2$.

The reason for your friend's confusion is that for each value of $y > 0$ that satisfies the equation $y + (y - c)^2 = r^2$, there are two points $(\sqrt{y}, y)$ and $(-\sqrt{y}, y)$ where the parabola $y = x^2$ intersects the curve $x^2 + (y - c)^2 = r^2$.